# Can I follow users, and if not why not?

Tags: support

Can I follow users, *and if not why not*? Seems like it would be a beneficent site feature, anyway.

Comment: I can't think why you would want to, perhaps you could elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For general questions about the SE network you can use [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Many questions have been asked already there, also [yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/205264). At the bottom of the Activity tab of a user's profile is a link to an RSS feed that contains recent posts and comments.

Comment: great, thanks. i thought it was ok to ask here?

Comment: @user3293056 your question is OK here, but it's often faster to search on Meta.SE.